# iOS App Development - Change icons on third party apps

Tags: ios, icons

Does apple allow an app to change the icons of other apps or is this functionality exclusive to their shortcuts app?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't do that. Even Shortcuts does not change an app's icon - it creates a shortcut with a custom icon.